# How to fill nan value with the previous available in the row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

I need to fill the nan value in a dataframe by using the previous available value in a row, as the data are timeseries. Here there is an example:

```
1   2   3   4
b   b   nan c
c   nan d   nan
d   nan nan c
```

What I need is:

```
1   2   3   4
b   b   b   c
c   c   d   d
d   d   d   c
```

I know the method fillna from panda, but the methods are only based on columns. I think about doing a transposition and after the use of the fillna method, but I would like to know if there are more efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ffill` along the first axis.

```
df.ffill(axis=1)

   1  2  3  4
0  b  b  b  c
1  c  c  d  d
2  d  d  d  c
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fill nan cells by value from row in up:

```py
df.ffill(axis=0)
```