# Pandas Pivot table cumsum() how to carry a value to the next column without np.NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to ask if there is a way to carry last known value over few columns when doing:

```
pvt_a = pd.pivot_table(data[data['Category']=='A'], values='Key',index='Store', columns='Support Status by Quarter', aggfunc='count')
pvt_a = pvt_a.cumsum(axis=1)
```

This is what I have:

[image]

but I need last known value from previous column in the same row so i.e. the highlighted would carry 1 over.

thanks

Comment: Hi, I see you're new here. Welcome! Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill nan value with the previous available in the row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087907/how-to-fill-nan-value-with-the-previous-available-in-the-row)

Comment: Please check ffill  ~

Comment: Thank you guys, i didn't know what to ask for.